# In which thread should I send analytics

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading, grand-central-dispatch

I have an `iOS` application where I track events and screens all over the app. In which thread it's better to send analytics?

Comment: Because it's not UI related you don't need to explicitly do it on the main thread, I've always done mine on the main thread because the analytic event is usually triggered by a button press event which happens on main thread.

Comment: Don't know for sure, but i think modern analytics tools manage this. If it is like i said, there is no difference from what queue you would send them. But to be 100% sure check documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a queue with

```
let g = DispatchQueue(label:"com.serial.analy")
```

And use or use `DispatchQueue.global()`

Answer (score 0):

I think it is best to check with your analytics library provider as it could potentially require to send them from the main thread.